# sql closed loop relations; what could go wrong?

Tags: sql, relationship, cyclic

I am working with a database with the following design. I read it is not a good practice to have closed loops in a database design, and i have more than one. But i cannot remember why. So not sure how this might affect me. Any examples how this could be dangerous?

[image: schematic of part of our database]

Edit: went through my ebooks, found what i was reading was **Beginning Database Design From Novice to Professional**, publisher: APRESS.
they just warn against this, but give a vague reason why. No, we are not using triggers. Anyone has a clearer explanation?
Thanks
Excerpt, p.109:

> A small company has employees who each
>   work for one of a number of different
>   small project groups. Each group and
>   all its employees are housed in one
>   particular room with larger rooms
>   housing several groups.We may require
>   information such as where each
>   employee is located, a particular
>   employee’s phone number, where to find
>   a particular group, which employees
>   work in each group, who is in each
>   room, and so on. One possible data
>   model is shown in Figure 5-7. Take a
>   moment to understand the data model
>   and the information it contains about
>   the number of groups in a room and so
>   on for this particular problem. The
>   model has redundant information. Can
>   you see what it is?

[image: example figure]

> With respect to Example 5-3, if we
>   regularly want to find an employee’s
>   phone number, we might think that the
>   top relationship in Figure 5-7 between
>   Employee and Room would be a useful
>   direct route. However, this same
>   information is very easily available
>   by an alternative route through Group.
>   We can find the employee’s (one only)
>   group and then find that group’s (one
>   only) room. This is a very simple
>   retrieval (it does not involve all the
>   complications with dates that plagued
>   the small hostel in Example 5-2).
>   However, the extra relationship is not
>   just unnecessary, it is dangerous.
>   With two routes for the same
>   information, we risk getting two
>   different answers unless the data is
>   very carefully maintained. Whenever an
>   employee changes group or a group
>   shifts rooms, there will be two
>   relationship instances to update.
>   Without very careful updating
>   procedures, we could end up having
>   that Jim is in Group A, which is in
>   Room 12, while the other route may
>   have Jim associated directly with Room
>   15. Redundant information is prone to inconsistencies and should always be
>   removed.

Comment: Can't see the "following design". Do you mean TableA has FK ref to TableB has FK ref to TableC has FK ref to TableA?

Comment: fixed link to design URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not had problems in the past using "closed loop" references between groups of tables (i.e. at least 3 in the relationship loop). The only issue I can think of would be if you use triggers, and even then it would only be a problem if you are updating the other tables in the "loop" in the trigger.

Do you have a reference for where you read this advice for not having closed loops?

To the others who commented the image can be seen if you copy the link to a new window: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMrwC.jpg

Comment: added the relative excerpt, and no we are not using triggers.

Comment: The example given in your book is a bit contrived. I don't see any major problems in your design but there might be an issue keeping the data consistent between the [Slab], [Plate] & [ReportCoolingBed] tables as you have key relationships between [Slab] -> [Plate] & [Slab] -> [ReportCoolingBed] and then a 1-1 relation between [Plate] & [ReportCoolingBed].
It might help to see the attributes of the primary/foreign keys used in each table.

Answer (score 5):

Not all databases have deferred relationship checking enabled and not all databases allow inserting two records into two different tables in one statement.

Imagine you have a `FOREIGN KEY` from `A` to `B` and from `B` to `A`.

Initially, both tables are empty.

How are you going to insert the very first record?

You cannot insert anything to `A` since it has to refer to a record in `B` (which is empty), and in the same way you cannot insert anything into `B`.

Comment: in my case, i have a 1-n relation from A to B, and then a 1-n relation from B to C, then a 1-n relation from A to C. there are different cases where we have loops too.

Comment: `@Slabo`: the case you just described contains no loops.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say that "it's not good practice to have closed loops". However, they do draw attention to a potential problem. So it would be a good habit to check all closed loops for the possibility of this problem.

The text book example seems quite clear to me. There are 2 ways in which the location/phone of the employee can be determined:

- Employee -> Group -> Room -> Phone
- or Employee -> Room -> Phone

This is like storing two variables for the same thing that need to be kept in synch. There will be the possibility that something goes wrong and the variables end up with different values - then you have to ask: "Which of the two is correct?"

So the text book example highlights the problem you have to watch our for. However, the problem really boils down to *semantics*. I.e. what do the relationships mean. In the text book example, both paths to `Room` mean exactly the same thing. If however the `Group -> Room` were merely a 'default' for each employee because senior employees could get their own room, or employees could temporarily be assigned to work somewhere else away from their group, then the additional relationship would be justified.

Moving onto your design, this is what you should do:

- Look for closed groups
- Assess the semantics/purpose/meaning of the relationships
- Check that you haven't just created two paths to exactly the same ***information***.

For example, you have:

- TestSample -> Coil -> Slab
- TestSample -> Plate -> Slab

(*Forgive the possibly absurd understanding of your terminology*.) Does this mean your test sample can be on 2 different slabs at the same time? Or does it mean your test sample will be made up of a plate and a coil that could have (but not necessarily) come from different slabs?